# Resetting ALL variables when running main() in a loop

Tags: python, variables, memory

I'm looking to run a program again when asking the user: "Do you want to run the program again". No going to exit, and yes looping around and running main again. However I've noticed that python keeps the old variable assignments stored. Is there a quick way to clear the memory so that when the program loops again stores new variables?

At the moment i've just got: Please close the program and reopen it! Want to make it more elegant:

Here's what i've got so far:

```
def main()
    print("Do you want to solve another problem?")
    answer = input()
    while answer not in["yes","no"]:
        answer = input()

    if answer == "yes":
        print("Please close the program and rerun it")
        #main() #<-this is not working as expected
    else:
        exit()
```

Comment: Don't use global variables? Which "old variable assignments" are being stored?

Comment: Yes. All variables should be local, and the logic that controls whether `main()` is run again should be outside of `main()`.

Comment: I got it working. Just a quick question. If I call main() inside main(), does that keep all variables already defined in the previous iteration, or does it reset it?

Comment: Calling a function creates a new stack frame, so all local variables are uninitialized. Global variables are not reset.

Comment: Is there a best practice work working locally for uninitialized variables? Would it just be a matter of setting all the variables as =None, before calling main() again? Would doing this clear the stack?Thanks @kindall

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is localize the variables and have clean up function to handle starting a new session.

```
def main()
    print("Do you want to solve another problem?")
    answer = input()
    while answer not in["yes","no"]:
        answer = input()

    if answer == "yes":
        answer = None
        print("Please close the program and rerun it")
        #main() #<-this is not working as expected
    else:
        exit()
```

The difference is `if answer == 'yes'` will set `answer = None` which clears it.